# parse.com user saved in object has no data when retrieved

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

I have a FriendRelation parse.com object.  It consists of 2 User objects. One is named **friend** and the other is called **user**.

The for loop ran below is run from a success block from a parse.com query.  It returns a user object but is empty of any of the attributes.

After this print, I print the same user but from the current user and it returns all of the populated attributes I need.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"FriendRelation"];
    [query whereKey:@"user" equalTo:self.user];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            self.friends = objects;
            for(PFObject *object in objects){
 
    for(PFObject *friendRelation in objects){
          PFUser *friend = [friendRelation objectForKey:@"user"];
          NSLog(@"%@friend name: ", friend);
          NSLog(@"%@user name: ", [PFUser currentUser]);
    }
```

Below are what each of the prints return:

print 1:

```
<PFUser:5frgh5:(null)> {
}friend name:
```

print 2

```
<PFUser:5frgh5:(null)> {
    friends =     (
        "<PFUser:mOUfJOSHlP:(null)> {\n}"
    );
    name = "John Doe";
    username = aadfasd;
}user name:
```

How do I extract a populated **user** from the FriendRelation object?

Comment: Can you include the original query? Did you try using the include constraint on user?

Comment: Hi Hector, I included the full query.  Do you know where I apply the include constraint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `includeKey:` constraint for the "user" column to the original query:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"FriendRelation"];
[query whereKey:@"user" equalTo:self.user];
[query includeKey:@"user"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
```